# Do all integrable functions on $[0,1]$ form a vector space?

Tags: functions, vector-spaces

Does the set of all functions integrable over $[0,1]$ form a vector space? 
(Here we are assuming "standard" definitions of addition and multiplication).

Here is what I have tried:

Define $\mathcal{F}=\lbrace f(x) | \int\limits_{0}^1f(x)dx\in\mathbb{R}\rbrace$. 
For $f,g,h\in\mathcal{F}$ the following hold:

I proved several of the properties (commutativity of addition, associativity of addition, additive identity with $z(x)=0$).  I am stuck as to how to prove that there is an additive inverse and multiplicative inverse for all $f\in\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: You just have to prove it is a *subspace* of the vector space of functions defined on $[0,1]*, which much less to prove, as addition of functions has all the required properties. regarding associativity, commutativity and distributivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, multiplication is not needed for vector space. What is needed is multiplication by scalar.

So, the operations are

$$(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x),\ (\alpha f)(x) = \alpha f(x), \forall f,g\in\mathcal F, \alpha\in\mathbb R$$

and we need to show that they are well defined. This is a direct consequence of linearity of integral:

$$\int(\alpha f+\beta g)(x)\,dx = \alpha\int f(x)\,dx + \beta\int g(x)\,dx.$$

Additive inverse is $(-f)(x) = -f(x)$.

The rest of the vector space axioms can be checked easily - they are consequence of the same axioms holding in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ennar: By "show that they well defined", do you mean show that $\alpha f + \beta g$ is \textit{also} an integrable function on $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: @ashman, yes. $\hphantom{a}$

Answer (score 1):

The additive inverse of f(x) is the obvious -f(x) or, equivalently, -1 times f.  The statement that "every f(x) has a multiplicative inverse" is [b]false[/b] with the obvious counter example f(x)= 0 for all x.  However, a **vector space** does not require multiplicative inverses nor even a definition of multiplying two vectors.